# Convert various number of arguments into a string?

Tags: python, string, f-string

I have the following function that create a name from the variable size arguments:

```
def create_name(*argv):
    """Create a name from passed arguments."""
    return f"%s" % "_".join(str(arg) for arg in argv)
```

When running pylint, i am getting the following warning.

```
 W1309: Using an f-string that does not have any interpolated variables (f-string-without-interpolation)
```

Just curious if any improvement can be made to resolve this warning.

Comment: Just remove the `f"%s" %` part. What purpose do you think it serves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression `f"%s" % "_".join(str(arg) for arg in argv)` breaks down like this:

- `f"%s"` is formatted with `"_".join(str(arg) for arg in argv)`, using the `%` operator
- `f"%s"` in turn is an interpolated string, but nothing is done to it since there's no `{}` in it, so `"%s"` would achieve the same
- formatting `"%s"` with another string using `%` just gets you the same string again, so the whole expression could just be `"_".join(str(arg) for arg in argv)`

So, these all work:

```
return "_".join(str(arg) for arg in argv)
return "%s" % "_".join(str(arg) for arg in argv)
return f'{"_".join(str(arg) for arg in argv)}'
```

But there's little reason not to use the first, the rest just adds complications and no functionality.

Specifically, you're issued that warning because interpolated strings (or 'f-strings') in Python expect expressions in `{}` to replace, but your f-string doesn't have any, so pylint is telling you you can just remove the `f`. Because your f-string "does not have any interpolated variables".